# Why did Ainz tell Aura not to set her alarm on her watch at 19:19 and 7:21?

Tags: overlord

I came across this in the Trivia section of [Bukubukuchagama](http://overlordmaruyama.wikia.com/wiki/Bukubukuchagama#Trivia) on Overlord Wiki:

> Giving the watch with her voice to Aura, Ainz told her not to set an alarm at 19:19 or 7:21. These numbers can be read as a sexual word in Japanese wordplay. It seems that she recorded her voice for an H-Game at that alarm.

Since I don't know Japanese, I am curious to know how they are read.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a [comment](http://overlordmaruyama.wikia.com/wiki/Bukubukuchagama#comm-text-8408) pointed out in the wiki page you provided, the words which the numbers represent seem to be a common thing in hentai games.

**For 19:19**:

> In Japanese when reading the time, or a string of numbers, it is often read as if each number is separate, for example, "One Nine One Nine". Doing this with 19:19 sounds a bit like "*Iku, Iku*" which translates to "*I'm cumming, I'm cumming!*".

**For 7:21**:

> Thanks to [ʞɹɐzǝɹ's](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/24048/some-kind-of-wordplay-in-overlord/24051?noredirect=1#comment34657_24051) comment we now know that it sounds a bit like "*Onanī*" which translates into "onanism" which is a synonym for "masturbation".

These are instances of [Goroawase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_wordplay#Goroawase) word play in Japanese, which takes advantage of the readings of digits to encode meaning in a string of numbers.

Comment: 19:19 down, now waiting for the 7:21 mystery to be solved...

Comment: @LePikastache It's probably something similar.

Comment: even if it's something similar, I'm still curious about how it is pronounced in Japanese that makes it a perverted sentence from Hentai Games

Comment: ０７：２１＝ [オナニー](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/onanism).

Comment: Additional note: this is called 'goroawase' in Japanese. Searching that term should give more examples, though not as explicit as these two :)

Comment: Now I can die in peace with this mystery solved

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Alagaros' answer, I'll try to explain it from another perspective.

As explained in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_characters), Kanji is adapted from Chinese letters (Hanzi). Originally, Hanzi was written based on the shape of the represented object but then undergoes evolution with the passage of time. For example [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Evo-r%C3%AC.svg).

Such a language habit is then evolving into using the existing characters to represent things. This is especially common with younger people (source: my Chinese lecturer). Think of it like the westerners using symbol characters to form smileys :D :P.

Now, the time 19:19 and 7:21 if written in kanji would be 一九一九 and 七二一 respectively.

一九 represents a kneeling person and a [Neo Armstrong Cyclone Jet Armstrong Cannon](http://gintama.wikia.com/wiki/Neo_Armstrong_Cyclone_Jet_Armstrong_Cannon) (alias to keep this relatively Safe For Work). And 七二一 represents either a big Neo Armstrong Cyclone Jet Armstrong Cannon or a Neo Armstrong Cyclone Jet Armstrong Cannon and a [manko](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjbtbi94qrHAhUDcI4KHfd3C8w&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.urbandictionary.com%2Fdefine.php%3Fterm%3Dmanko&ei=oQXPVZvhKIPguQT3763gDA&usg=AFQjCNH2vsyqh2iCwcmNE9pshbAMa_j8Fw&sig2=5miCV6mM0WQXOcSjTcBjjQ&bvm=bv.99804247,d.c2E).

Comment: I don't believe this sort of word play is intended, nor interpreted this way.